# what is a reference distribution?

Tags: yocto

I needed to understand what is poky in Yocto, so I typed the following question in Google:

> what is poky in yocto

The first answer that I got was

> Poky is a **reference distribution** of the Yocto Project. It contains the
>   OpenEmbedded Build System (BitBake and OpenEmbedded Core) as well as a
>   set of metadata to get you started building your own distro.

Then I tried to understand what is a `reference distribution`. I tried googling for it but came up empty.

Can someone explain what is a `reference distribution`? Are there `non reference distributions`? What does it mean for a piece of software to be a  `reference distribution`?

P.S. I do know what Linux distros are. What I don't know is the meaning of the phrase `reference distribution` in the context of the Yocto project.

Comment: The word "reference" is used to mean "example" in this context. Poky is a reference for you to use in building your own distribution. It's a minimal working example for you to understand and build upon.

Comment: @David Thank you. Am I correct in my understanding that different branches in Poky would simply mean change of kernel used by the distro (speaking in the broadest possible terms) ?

Comment: Poky's branches correspond to version, Rocko for Yocto is the equivalent to  Artful for ubuntu.

Comment: @Nayfe Version of what?

Comment: Yocto Project version

Comment: @Nayfe If I understand you correctly then whenever there is a new release of Yocto, there is a new branch of poky. If no, then could you please provide more clarification.

Comment: That's it, Yocto regroups some tools into a common project, and Poky is the result of it, sort of :)

Comment: @Nayfe I'm a little confused. From David's response my understanding was that `Poky` is a Linux distro. But now you are telling me it is not. Can you please clarify what is exactly `Poky`?

Comment: BTW i prefer this definition `The BitBake and OE components combine together to form a reference build host, historically known as Poky`. Poky is indeed a `reference Linux distribution` but as you can see in `http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky` it contains tools, meta layers, etc to build it. What is confusing is that Poky contains Poky distribution policy layer. Maybe someone can explain it better :)

Comment: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases lists the releases with their names and numbers in release order for convenience.

Comment: This [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-overview/reference-distribution) will answer I feel.

Answer (score -1):

I understand what you need. click the [yocto-tutorial](https://github.com/vsivanagulu/yocto-tutorial)
 for better understanding of Yocto Project and Yocto Reference Distro's(poky)

Comment: Even this [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-overview/reference-distribution/) will give a short and crispy answer.